# How to work around expiring tableau session

Tags: http, security, session, tableau-api, session-timeout

i want to download the data in this table:
https://public.tableau.com/profile/oregon.health.authority.covid.19#!/vizhome/OregonCOVID-19CasesbyZIPCode-SummaryTable/CasesbyZIPCodeSummaryTable?publish=yes

click a cell, and then click it again do unselect it.  this "activates" the table.  then click the download icon at the bottom of the table, and select "data" (this option is disabled without "activating" the table as described).  in the window that pops up, switch to the "full data" tab and check the "show all columns" checkbox.  then right click "download all rows as a text file", and you get a link like this, which downloads a csv.

`https://public.tableau.com/vizql/w/OregonCOVID-19CasesbyZIPCode-SummaryTable/v/CasesbyZIPCodeSummaryTable/vudcsv/sessions/8B9BA06A1053493B90D50491CE080449-0:0/views/5592189642670210780_8788956907388558289?showall=true&underlying_table_id=Migrated%20Data&underlying_table_caption=Full%20Data`

the session uid in the url expires after a few minutes, after which you get a `410` ("gone") response.

how can i access this data long-term with no manual steps?  selenium/webdriver comes to mind, is there anything more direct?

Answer (score 0):

One other way is indeed to scrape the rendered data. I've made [this python tableau scraper library](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping) which extracts data from Tableau worksheets. You need to find the Tableau URL (using network tab of developer tools). In this case it's the following :

```
GET https://public.tableau.com/views/OregonCOVID-19CasesbyZIPCode-SummaryTable/CasesbyZIPCodeSummaryTable
```

The following code extract the table you are/were looking for :

```py
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS

url = "https://public.tableau.com/views/OregonCOVID-19CasesbyZIPCode-SummaryTable/CasesbyZIPCodeSummaryTable"

ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
dashboard = ts.getDashboard()

for t in dashboard.worksheets:
    #show worksheet name
    print(f"WORKSHEET NAME : {t.name}")
    #show dataframe for this worksheet
    print(t.data)
```

[run this code on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/TableauOregonCovid)